# How to make geoencoding with Google Maps faster?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, google-maps, dataframe

This is my code to extract latitudes and longitudes from location addresses in a CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import time

GOOGLE_MAPS_API_URL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'
API_key= 'the-key'

def gmaps_geoencoder(address):
    req = requests.get(GOOGLE_MAPS_API_URL+'?address='+address+'&key='+API_key)
    res = req.json()
    result = res['results'][0]
    lat = result['geometry']['location']['lat']
    lon = result['geometry']['location']['lng']
    return lat, lon

input_csv_file = r'path\to\location_list_100.csv'
output_csv_file = r'path\to\location_list_100_new.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(input_csv_file)

#size of chunks of data to write to the csv
chunksize = 10

t = time.time()
for i in range(len(df)):
    place = df['ADDRESS'][i]
    lat, lon, res = gmaps_geoencoder(place)
    df['Lat'][i] = lat
    df['Lon'][i] = lon

    df.to_csv(output_csv_file,
          index=False,
          chunksize=chunksize) #size of data to append for each loop

print('Time taken: '+str(time.time() - t)+'s')
```

It took `47.75818920135498s` for 100 records. That is, ~0.5s per record. How do I make it faster? I have ~ 1 million records to convert, and at this rate, it would take almost 6 days to finish the process!!! What is taking the time here: iterating through the dataframe, or fetching data with the gmaps API? If its the former, I suppose there should be some way to make it faster. But if its the latter, is there any fix?

Comment: i think there is a indentation problem at line `df.to_csv`, can you recheck that?

Comment: No, I wrote it purposefully like that so that in case if the code is interrupted, it can still write whatever it extracted into the new csv.

Comment: thats the reason why you are getting 47 secs.

Comment: for 100 records 100 file write operation takes time

Comment: if you don't want  interruption you can always use `try except` and print log of error so you can know at which record there is a problem in the csv

Comment: Its 10 operations actually, as the chunksize is 10. For 1 million records, I guess I can make the chunksize 1000. The reason I want to write in chunks instead of waiting for the entire thing to end is, in case of any accident, I don't want time to have been wasted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    place = df['ADDRESS'][i]
    lat, lon, res = gmaps_geoencoder(place)
    df['Lat'][i] = lat
    df['Lon'][i] = lon

    df.to_csv(output_csv_file,
          index=False,
          chunksize=chunksize)
```

use this

```
df[['Lat', 'Lon', 'res']] = pd.DataFrame(df['ADDRESS'].apply(lambda x: gmaps_geoencoder(x)).values.tolist())

df.to_csv(output_csv_file,
          index=False,
          chunksize=chunksize)
```

[Refer to this link for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51283438/7053679)

Comment: I get this error with your code: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`

Comment: reffer that link in my answer. in that person named jezrael has given time taken to execute that in the comments. which could be helpful to you

Comment: Thanks. I tried the time taken for 100 locations with both the codes, your lambda and my for loop. The lambda based solution took `62.94639539718628s` and the for loop based one took `43.16185998916626s`. I'm a bit surprised, as I thought the lambda based solution should have been faster, from common knowledge!

Comment: I restarted the kernel and have run it a few time more. Interestingly, the lambda based code now finishes running in 25-30 seconds, while the for loop based code takes 35-40 seconds.

Comment: instead of df['address'] use df.iloc[:, 'column number of address']