# Pandas lambda multiple argument in return

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda, arguments

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def ced(x):
    return x+1, x+2, x+3


df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2],[10,20]], columns=['a','b'])


df['x'], df['y'], df['z'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: ced(x)) 


print(df)
```

error:

> line 11, in 
>       df['x'], df['y'], df['z'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: ced(x))  ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

this thing works for

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def ced(x):
    return x+1, x+2


df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2],[10,20]], columns=['a','b'])


df['x'], df['y'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: ced(x)) 


print(df)
```

output:

```
    a   b  x   y
0   1   2  2  11
1  10  20  3  12
```

I don't know what is the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest change function for return `Series` and subset of new columns:

```
def ced(x):
    return pd.Series([x+1, x+2, x+2])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2],[10,20]], columns=['a','b'])


df[['x','y', 'z']] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: ced(x)) 

print(df)
    a   b   x   y   z
0   1   2   2   3   3
1  10  20  11  12  12
```

Another solution is create `DataFrame` by constructor:

```
def ced(x):
    return x+1, x+2, x+2

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2],[10,20]], columns=['a','b'])


df[['x','y', 'z']] = pd.DataFrame(df['a'].apply(lambda x: ced(x)).values.tolist())
print(df)
    a   b   x   y   z
0   1   2   2   3   3
1  10  20  11  12  12
```

Comment: can you tell which one will be faster first one or the second for large dataframe?

Comment: @Nihal - I think second one.

Comment: @Nihal - Just tested `In [260]: %timeit df[['x','y', 'z']] = pd.DataFrame(df['a'].apply(lambda x: ced(x)).values.tolist())
3.05 ms ± 99.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [262]: %timeit df[['x','y', 'z']] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: ced(x))
349 ms ± 8.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: with `df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)`